# TensorFlowコンテナをDockerに作成し、チュートリアルをしたい

Tags: macos, docker, tensorflow

お世話になっております。
環境
OS: OS X EL Capitan
Docker: 1.10.2

DockerToolのDocker Quickstart Terminalを使用してます。

現在TensorFlowコンテナをDockerに作成し、実行しようとしています。

しかし、

```
$ docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

と実行したのですが、下記画像のようになり、ここからどうしていいのかがわかりません。

[image: コマンドラインSS]

`The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/`とあるので`http://localhost:8888/`など試したのですが、ページが表示されない状況です。
何を打ち込んでも反応がないのでここで現在止まっている状況になります。

コンテナ作成は上記の他に

```
$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow
$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

を試しましたが、どれも画像と同じ結果になりました。

DockerでTensorFlowを試されている方いらっしゃいましたら、助言頂けないでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tensorflowを使った事がないので、どの様な結果を望んでいるかは知りませんが、私の環境で質問者様と同じ様にコマンドを打つと下記の様な結果になりました。

[image: 結果]

打ったコマンド

```
$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

私はdockerホスト側でlocalhostと入力していますが、boot2dockerを使ってらっしゃるのでしたら、ポートフォワード等の経路は作成されていますか？
また、dockerホストのIPアドレス:8888をlocalhost:8888の代わりに入力してみてはいかがでしょう？